# Can't run shell php script from wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

How to fix user rights? 
When doing from the commandline - sudo 'the command with params' - it works. 
Like this looks the code which is calling the script:

```
$command = "php /etc/blabla/index.php $stuff $more_stuff";

        $handle = popen(" ".$command." 2>&1", "r");

        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $line = fgets($handle, 100);
            if ($line === false)
                break;

            $read .= $line;
        }
        $exit_code = pclose($handle);
```

USER RIGHTS: (I tried even setting 777 and www-data as owner). Loooks like it doesn't work:

```
    /etc/
drwxr-xr-x 68 root root  4096 Dec  1 10:23 etc

/etc/bla/
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data  4096 Dec  8 16:08 bla/

/etc/bla/index.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data 1433 Dec  8 14:28 index.php
```

Comment: Your web server won't have sudo access, and absolutely shouldn't.  So anything you have to sudo, won't work from a non root environment.  The sudo may or may not actually be required.  Can you show the permissions and ownership (`ls -l` ) on /etc, /etc/blabla, and /etc/blabla/index.php ?

Comment: @DanFarrell I've made a comment